# SFDX: Deploying workflows with email alerts using org wide email addresses

Tags: workflow, salesforcedx, email-alert

I have an issue where I am not able to deploy workflows to my scratch org because the workflow contains email alerts that specify an Org-wide email address as the sender. The error I get is: `You must specify a verified org wide email address for this sender type`.

I understand that the error comes from the fact that for an org wide email address, it must be manually verified by clicking on a link sent to that address after it has been added to Salesforce. For the scenario of deploying these to scratch orgs, I considered it unfeasible to manually setup 5+ different org wide emails as a pre-deploy step, especially when the email accounts are owned by my client and not myself.

I also considered creating a script to manually change the sender type of these email alerts to send from the default user instead of an org wide email address (according to the [metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm), that would be changing the senderType and and senderAddress tags in the XML file). However, I would still have an issue where even if successfully deployed these workflows with a modified sender, if a developer made workflow changes and pulled them using `sfdx force:source:pull`, then they would pull down those script changes which we wouldn't want to commit.

This seems like it would be a relatively common problem, yet I haven't found any similar questions online. Does anyone have any experience dealing with this issue or have any suggestions?

Comment: I have this issue as well, did you have any luck in resolving this?

Answer (score 6):

something so simple and still such a big blocker. For now here is what we have been doing.

I have a **[nodejs script](https://github.com/davidbrowaeys/DXB/blob/master/src/commands/dxb/org/setdefault.ts)** that replace

```
<senderType>OrgWideEmailAddress</senderType><!--orgwideemail-->
```

by

```
<senderType>CurrentUser</senderType><!--orgwideemail-->
```

I marked the line in my meta.xml file by commenting `<!--orgwideemail-->` so I know the one I want to update. Then I make sure I don't commit this changes to my branch.

**Another option** is to take it out of your metadata and make that config a manual post deployment step.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the Org Wide Email Address via the REST API (POST) and then subsequently issue a PATCH request (empty body) against the new record and it magically becomes verified.

This is surely an 'undocumented feature' that might be fixed some day but until that day, it's a rather painless workaround to a significant gap in SFDX and metadata support.

Background:

https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A000043KVUw

Comment: That day came a while ago, this hack no longer works