# Scratch org - Pushing email alert which are using OrgWideAddress

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, cicd

I want to push the code which has email alerts. However, it is not allowing because in the email alert its using org-wide address.

I searched and it seems not possible at this moment(v50.0). However, putting (somewhat duplicate) question to know if is there any way to bypass the issues for the pushing the code.

E.g. any setting in config file to mask the error. It's fine if it didn't create the org-wide-address which I can create later.

***PS - This is mainly requiring for CICD. There is additional overhead while deploying to actual sandbox to replace the string in workflow email alert.***

Comment: It sounds like you already found another question on this on SFSE. Which one was it?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244217/sfdx-deploying-workflows-with-email-alerts-using-org-wide-email-addresses 
It was similar, we do have unlocked package and mdapi so i can use both, only thing troubling is what if tomorrow someone forgot to change similar setup.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to rethink what you are going to deploy to your scratch org, and also not to deploy metadata that relies on the org's configuration that can not be deployed.

The reason not to deploy this, in your situation, is that org wide addresses are org-specific, not project-specific. So you will face issues deploying that. You can't even deploy those as change sets if you wanted to (the addresses, not the emails).

Think about it this way: scratch orgs are a convenient way of deploying an application's metadata for testing and development. If your app were to be **installed** in an org, you wouldn't want to set the org addresses for the package's subscriber, right? This is a task the administrator should do **after** installing/deploying the app. So, logically, it should be left outside the project/repository.

This logic works for many other components too, such as case support processes and milestones.

Comment: As of now, we're changing the word only to make it work. As i said, as a part of our CICD process we need to validate every change for scratch org as well(so that new devloper can create and work on scratch org swiftly). 

For sandbox &/or prod we're creating before deployment so that it won't break deployment.

Comment: Regarding change-sets, we're not creating on-the-fly orgs so its fine there.

Comment: Curious to know your thoughts on unlocked packages with CICD for single org(not app-exchange one)? If I keep this outside of my scratch org/configuration, admin needs to do each time we deploy the package. So main intention is avoid repetitive work and chance to human error.

Comment: Packaging is not an exclusive feature of AppExchange apps. You can develop internal apps for your own organizations and customers. They don't need to do this every time you deploy your package (unless your admin is using a scratch org too, which is advised against, since it is an environment suited for code development).

Comment: The idea is to deploy the "base app" and let admins configure it on production. A custom apex action, for example, which can be used in a flow, should be developed and tested with a scratch org. Once deployed, the admin can add it to a flow on a sandbox. Bug fixes and new deployments of the same app (but different version) won't undo the flow configuration (so there is no rework for the admin).

Comment: Actually we'll be using that email alerts for different modules[PBs to be specific](not at single places) of package, so if I remove it out of package it will not work. So as of now its hard to remove. But for future packages will surely consider to make those out of packages.